# Occlusion of light with very fast objects

Tags: special-relativity, speed-of-light

Take this graphic:
[image: Look at it]

On the left there is a light emitter, which can fire light on command, towards the right. There are also two receptors, A and B, both $1$ light second away from the emitter. `receptor B` is in the path of the light, and `receptor A` is not. `receptor B` also has a velocity of $0.9c$ to the right.

Imagine that at time $0$, light is emitted from the box marked `emitter`. (before that time no light was emitted) If I understand the speed of light correctly, it will contact `receptor B` after $1$ second, even though it is moving at $0.9c$ away from the emitter.

Now imagine this. At time $0.5$, you `receptor A` down so that it would come in contact with the path of the light. Would receptor A be hit by the light after $1$ second? If so, would that prevent `receptor B` from being hit by the light?

Comment: Is B moving at the velocity constantly, immediately (in lab frame) after the emission of the photon, or always?

Comment: always, the position at time `0` is 1 light second away though.

Comment: After one second in which frame of reference?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes the light that is emitted from the emitter, would reach receptor "A" after a time period of 1 second, which means the distance that the light traveled is 299,792.458 km's.

However, during the time that the light has departed from the emitter, and is moving toward receptor "A", receptor "B" is rapidly moving off to the right. By the time that the light reaches the receptor "A" position, receptor "B" has already traveled 269,813.212 km's away from that position, and there will be even  further movement off to the right before the light reaches this receptor "B".

Overall, if receptor "A" was left in its original position and thus does not block the line of sight leading to receptor "B", the light would reach receptor "B" after 4.359 seconds. Thus receptor "B" has traveled  (269,813.212 km's * 4.359) = 1,176,088.526 km's during this time period.

Now if the emitter and receptor "B" were mounted on a common frame, here too we would measure a time period of 1 second for the light to move across this 299,792.458 km's distance between the emitter and the receptor. If we then accelerated this common frame up to 0.9c off to the right, external viewers, who have not accelerated, would see that it takes 4.359 seconds for the light to leave the emitter and reach the receptor.

However, due to time dilation, clocks on board the moving frame would only measure 1.9 seconds ( 4.359 sec * 0.436 ). But it also is to be noted that a clock located at receptor "B" would be lagging behind a clock  located the emitter, by 0.9 of a second. Thus if it was agreed that the light would be emitted from the emitter at t=0 sec, the clock located at receptor "B" would therefore indicate t=1 sec ( 1.9 sec - 0.9 sec = 1 sec ) when the light finally reaches this receptor end.

Thus from the moving frames point of view, they will still measure the speed of the light as being 299,792.458 km/s. Yes, due to length contraction, the length of the frame has contracted from 299,792.458 km's, to 130,676.503 km's, but for those on board the moving frame, they are totally unaware of this contraction and thus to them the frame is still 299,792.458 km's long.

Thus 299,792.458 km's * 1 sec = the speed of light.

Answer (score 0):

> Would receptor A be hit by the light after 1 second?

Yes because they are separated by (1 light second) in the same frame of reference.

> If so, would that prevent receptor B from being hit by the light?

Not necessarily, it depends on the size (thickness) of the ray. If receptor A displaces receptor B below the line of contour of the ray, then receptor B will be unable to be exited by the light.

Comment: Size and thickness can be more easily referred to as 'coherence' of their frequencies